# Auto-generate ReST web services documentation/WADL

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, rest, openrasta

We are creating ReST Web Services using ASP.NET and OpenRasta.

Is there any tool that can could help us:

- create WADL file
- or/and create human readable API documentation similar which decribed resources/HTTP 
  methods supported for each resource, etc ?

Comment: When doing ReST with WCF you get this for free: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OpenRasta, it'd be possible to use a UriDecorator to have help-like URIs defined for your resources (such as /myResource$help). You can then rewrite the URI before parsing to something yo can document easily, parse teh uri, find the resource type, and rewrite to /help/{resourcetype}

From there you register a resource for your help system:
    ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType()
       .AtUri("/help/{resourceType}")
       .HandledBy()
       .RenderedByXxx()

Then you can create your handler to return the documentation about a resource. You could for example use the IOperationCreator service to know which http methodds are available and with what input arguments, use the ICodecRepository to see what media types may be accepted as input, and potentially what a media type serialization would look like by calling the codec and generating an html friendly view of it.

That's definitly an area we're going to work on for the next version.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [REST Describe & Compile](http://tomayac.de/rest-describe/latest/RestDescribe.html) should do the trick.

> On the WADL developer site Marc Hadley
>   maintains a command line tool named
>   WADL2Java. The ambitious goal of REST
>   Describe & Compile is to provide sort
>   of WADL2Anything. So what REST
>   Describe & Compile does is that it:
>
> - **Generates new WADL files in a completely interactive way.**
> - Lets you upload and edit existing WADL files.
> - Allows you to compile WADL files to source code in various programming
>     languages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link. Interesting indeed, but I was after a tool that would generate WADL(or equivalent HTML) automatically(for instance by decorating the REST methods at source code level), rather than in a completely interactive way.

Comment: Generating code from wadl files is introducing a lot of coupling that's gonna break rest principles at some point or another.